# How retrieve job config via groovy web console?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have Jenkins with several hundreds of jobs, and I need to find job which runs specified gradle task. I see following solution
1.retrieve all jobs (Jenkins.instance.projects)
2.iterate over them
3.get xml config and verify presence of substring

The question is how to retrieve xml representation from  hudson.model.FreeStyleProject? Or may be this data stored as map, than the question will be how it is called and how get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something similar before but using a shell script. Not sure if that approach is useful for you but just in case:

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/
grep WORD */config.xml
```

Also the next groovy script that can list all the FreeStyleProject name and gradle tasks:

```
def builderFilter = {  builder -> builder.class == hudson.plugins.gradle.Gradle.class }

jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.class).each{ job ->
  job.getBuilders().findAll(builderFilter).each{ gradleStep -> 
    gradleStep.each { gradleItem -> 
      println(job.getDisplayName() + ' ' + gradleItem.getTasks())
    } 
  }
}
```